# Drupal 8 Webform: how to display text input on one page on the next page?

Tags: drupal-8, wizard, drupal-webform, multi-step

I am trying to develop a multistep webform in Drupal 8 using Webform 8.x-5.1. I have written a WebformHandler that extends `Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase` and made it available to the webform.

In the first step of the webform, I collect a text-field. I would like to display the value of that text-field in an HTML element (`Advanced HTML/Text` or `Basic HTML`) on the second page after doing some computation.

I have overwritten `submitForm()` in the WebformHandler and in it assign the value I want to the HTML element as follows:

```
$form['elements']['page_name']
     ['advanced_html_element']['#text'] = '...my HTML...';
```

Using `ksm()` I can see that this assignment works, but the the HTML element is not rendered with my HTML: the element is either invisible or contains the initial value set up in the form editor.

Clearly I'm missing something. Should I be using something other than `submitForm`? Can anyone help me?

Comment: I've managed to progress by working around the immediate problem: I use a `computed Twig` element and have the computed value automatically updated by Ajax. However, I still have no solution to the general case of how to display on page N data collected on page N-1.

Comment: The Webform module seems to me to have a heavy bias towards contact forms (webform submission data etc., which I explicitly do not need) and very little support for wizards (e.g. session data). Perhaps it is just that there is more documentation on the former.

Comment: What I have discovered in the meantime is that the assignment to `$form[...]`is supposed to be in `alterForm()`, though I cannot yet see the changed values in the elements displayed by the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a long haul, but I've finally worked out how to do what I want to. The following works for me.

Firstly, I discovered the method `validateForm` in `WebformHandlerBase`. On each page in a form with multiple pages, you will find that the following methods are called in the order given here:

- `submitForm` (called once)
- `alterForm`(called possibly more than once)
- `validateForm` (called once)

The name `validateForm` leads me to believe I may be misusing this method, but that is where I set up the elements on the following page that I wish to programmatically initialise. It works, so what the hey!

In `validateForm`, I initialise the elements that appear on the following page as follows:

```
$form_state->setValue(<element name>, <data structure>);
```

The `<element name>` is the name you give the element in the form editor ("Build" tab). The `<data structure>` has to be correct, of course: I suggest you find the appropriate structure by first filling in the element on the next page manually and seeing what turns up in `$form_state`.

There is also a `$form_state->getValue(<element name>)`, which seems to me to mean that `$form_state` can also be used for storing session data, say in hidden fields. I initially used `Drupal::service('tempstore.private')->get('xxx')` for storing data that had to be available across page boundaries, but `$form_state` might be a cleaner solution.

I hope this helps someone: I spent a horribly long time trying to get this to work.

Comment: Man, you sure did help me out here!  It is really counter-intuitive putting setValue in the validateForm function.  Did you ever figure out if there was a better way or is this what you ended up with?  In the interest of getting done with my project I'm going with this but I'm genuinely curious if this is the right solution.

Thanks!